# Cannot deserialize previously serialized XML with c# xmlserializer

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer, xsd.exe

I have to use an externally given xml structure (huge).
I use the xsd tool of visual studio to generate classes that should be (de)serialized using xmlserializer.
Since we switched from VS2010 to VS2012 (but still targeting .NET 4.0), I have problems deserializing the XML. I broke it down to the following code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[XmlRootAttribute("DecoderParameter", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class DecoderParameterType
{
    private string[] decoderUpdatePointsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "integer")]
    public string[] DecoderUpdatePoints
    {
        get
        {
            return this.decoderUpdatePointsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.decoderUpdatePointsField = value;
        }
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    #region Public Methods and Operators

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var fileName = "c:\\temp\\test.xml";

        var deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DecoderParameterType));

        var output = new DecoderParameterType { DecoderUpdatePoints = new[] { "5", "7", "9" } };

        using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            deserializer.Serialize(fs, output);
        }

        using (var sr = new XmlTextReader(fileName))
        {
            var myParameter = (DecoderParameterType)deserializer.Deserialize(sr);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This code snippet fails with an Exception:

> *System.Xml.XmlException: 'None' is an invalid XmlNodeType.*

It works if I remove "DataType = integer" from the XmlAttributeAttribute.

Now I have the following questions:

- Why does installing .NET4.5 change the behaviour of a .NET4.0 - program? Or is this not the case and I am missing something? (Before I installed VS2012, this worked fine! Now it is neither in VS2010 nor in VS2012 working)
- What side effects has the removal of the datatype declaration?
- Which other datatype declarations are also affected? I have a lot of these declarations in the generated code, not only integer (nonNegativeInteger, date, etc...).

**Update**: The problem occurs only if the variable is an array.

Kind regards

Comment: I had a similar error occur to me once, but the problem wasn't the .NET version. The XML itself had one of its nested items removed, and a ReadEndElement() would read the root end tag prematurely. I would first check the integrity of the XML content itself.

Comment: I checked this; the XML seems to be fine. I created a small program just doing the above. If I start it on a machine having only .NET 4.0, it works. If it has 4.5, it fails.

Comment: I found something that appears similar.  Read through this and see if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689305/serialization-breaks-in-net-4-5

Comment: @Dave: Thank you, this was very helpful; the configuraiton entry did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first bullet is the easy one:

> - Why does installing .NET4.5 change the behaviour of a .NET4.0 - program?

Because .NET 4.5 is an over-the-top install, not a side-by-side install. When you install .NET 4.5 you are *changing the 4.0 assemblies*. The act of targeting 4.0 vs 4.5 simply determines whether the IDE will let you reference 4.5 **specific** features. Even when targeting 4.0, once you install 4.5 you are using the 4.5 implementation with any code-changes (bug-fixes, changed behaviors, and new bugs) associated with 4.5.

Comment: Are there any documented/"intentional" changes in behavior of old code under 4.5 (i.e not bug fixes or new bugs)?