# Office Plugin - Generated Xml Serializer can't find assembly in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, xml-serialization

Here's a problem which cost me a whole day. I figured I'd post the solution in case anyone else hits it.

I have a .NET Office plug-in which calls an ASMX web service. It gets a valid XML response, but the XmlSerializationReader can't deserialize the response properly. It fails to find one of my DLLs, and throws a FileNotFoundException.

The basic structure is this:

**Utility Assembly** -- contains some commonly-used utility classes which DTO's depend on.

```
namespace MyCompany.CommonUtilities
{
    [Serializable]
    public class UtilityClass
    {
        // Various fields and properties..
    }
}
```

**DTO Assembly** -- contains serializable objects for web service calls

```
using MyCompany.CommonUtilities;

namespace MyCompany.DtoObjects
{
    [Serializable]
    public class WebResponseDto
    {
        // Various other fields and properties..

        public UtilityClass Property1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This all worked great under .NET 3.5, and still does. If I run our old plugin, built against 3.5, everything works.

What happened though, is that in .NET 4.5 they completely reworked the way Xml serializers are generated at runtime. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14699617/3183464 and the README for .NET 4.5. The end result is that the Xml Serializer can't find the correct DLL for my Utilities project.

When I compile to .NET 4.5 the web service returns a properly serialized object, but it can't be deserialized on the client side. Instead I just get

`Exception: There is an error in XML document (1, 997).`

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyCompany.CommonUtilities, Version=6.0.0.23028, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMyCompanyService.Read101_WebResponseDto(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMyCompanyService.Read258_WebMethodResponse()
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer285.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
```

Which was confusing, since the Utilities DLL was already loaded before the webservice was even called.

Looking into the Fusion logs, I saw two distinct load events for the utility assembly. The first was when my Visio plugin first loaded, since it depends on the utility classes:

```
LOG: DisplayName = MyCompany.CommonUtilities, Version=6.0.0.23028, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office14/
Calling assembly : MyCompany.VisioAddIn, Version=6.0.0.23028, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office14/MyCompany.CommonUtilities.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office14/MyCompany.CommonUtilities/MyCompany.CommonUtilities.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office14/MyCompany.CommonUtilities.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office14/MyCompany.CommonUtilities/MyCompany.CommonUtilities.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/MyUser/Documents/DevProjects/VisioAddIn/bin/Debug/MyCompany.CommonUtilities.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\DevProjects\VisioAddIn\bin\Debug\MyCompany.CommonUtilities.dll
```

Notice the context: It calls `Assembly.LoadFrom()`, and it finds the DLL.

But then later, the serialization assembly generated at run-time tries to load the same assembly in order to deserialize a DTO, and can't find it:

```
LOG: DisplayName = MyCompany.CommonUtilities, Version=6.0.0.23028, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office14/
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office14/MyCompany.CommonUtilities.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office14/MyCompany.CommonUtilities/MyCompany.CommonUtilities.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office14/MyCompany.CommonUtilities.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Office/Office14/MyCompany.CommonUtilities/MyCompany.CommonUtilities.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed
```

See what happened?

The assembly generated at runtime doesn't realize it needs to look in the folder where my plug-in lives. It just calls `Assembly.Load()`, which uses the default load context.

Since it's running as part of Visio.EXE, Fusion searches the obvious place: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Office`, and doesn't find anything. Result: File not found.

Answer (score 1):

### Some things which didn't work:

**Configure .NET to use legacy serialization generation.**

```
<xmlSerializer useLegacySerializerGeneration="true"/>
```

This didn't seem to do anything. Also, the only way to do this would have been to add a Visio.exe.config file to the Program Files folder, and this has all sorts of Group Policy and permissions implications. Regardless, it didn't work.

**Project Properties > Build > "Generate serialization assembly" set to "On"**

This generated a serialization DLL, but the DLL wasn't found by Fusion just like the utility DLL wasn't found. .NET's serialization engine isn't looking in the right place.

### What did work

Attaching an event handler to the AppDomain and catching exceptions when `Assembly.Load()` fails.

I check to see if the assembly is one of mine. If so, I look to see if it's already loaded -- yes, Fusion can fail to load an assembly which is already loaded. If it's not loaded, I look in my plugin's folder to see if I can find the right DLL.

Result: Everything works again.

```
public void PlugInStartup()
{
    // (other stuff...)

    // This allows dynamically-generated DLLs (Xml serializers) to find our DLLs.
    // Because they're not in C:\Program Files\Office, they often can't be found.

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += FindUnresolvedAssembly;
}

private Assembly FindUnresolvedAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string fileName = args.Name.Split(',')[0] + ".dll";

    if (!fileName.Contains("MyCompany"))
        // Not our problem
        return null;

    Assembly[] loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

    Assembly alreadyLoadedAssembly = loadedAssemblies
        .FirstOrDefault(a => a.FullName == args.Name);

    if (alreadyLoadedAssembly != null)
        return alreadyLoadedAssembly;

    try
    {
        string 
            pluginDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),
            assemblyPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(pluginDir, fileName);

        if (File.Exists(assemblyPath))
            return Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
    }
    catch
    { }

    return null;
}
```